# Delete account with user data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

When user click on button i want to delete user account with user collection. My collection id is same as user account id, i success delete account but collection is not deleted. Im not sure but server give me code 400.

```
export const Delete = () => async (
  dispatch,
  getState,
  { getFirebase, getFirestore }
) => {
  dispatch({ type: ChangeStart });
  const firebase = getFirebase();
  const firestore = getFirestore();
  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

  const userId = getState().firebase.auth.uid;


  await user
    .delete()
    .then(function () {
      firestore.collection("users").doc(userId).delete();
      firebase.logout();
    })
    .catch((error) => {

     dispatch({ type: ChangeFail, payload: error.message });
    });
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: please post screenshot of your database structure  and the error you are getting.

Comment: @Dharmaraj, only one error when firebase ask me re-authorize.

Comment: Have you specified rules? for deleting?

Comment: @Dharmaraj,  Yes, this is the problem, I want to delete the collection only when the account has been deleted.Because deleting may require re-authorize

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your database rules. Let me check if you have given proper access.

Comment: Try adding `,delete` after `allow read, write:` and let me know if it works

Comment: @Dharmaraj, problem with rules. But how i can delete account and collection together?

Comment: Can you try adding the delete rule and see if it deletes the documents? If it does then I'll say you how to delete both at once

Comment: @Dharmaraj,  `delete`  works only with authorization, when account is delete going out from account and firestore ask for delete but it cant becase of rules

Comment: I'm not understanding what do mean by authorization. Can you elaborate that? And if you want to delete document when user account is deleted, enclose the document deleting code in `onDelete()` trigger as shown in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events). This will delete your documents as soon as your user is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I delete user data with Firebase function like this:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();


exports.DeleteAll = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {
  const userId = user.uid;
  admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).delete();
});
```